# $\mathscr{M}_{\beta´}^{\beta}(id)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

> In each one of the following cases, find $\mathscr{M}_{\beta´}^{\beta}(id)$. >The vector space in each case is $\mathbb{R}^3$.
>
> a) $\beta=\{(1,1,0),(-1,1,1),(0,1,2)\}\\\beta´={(2,1,1),(0,0,1),(-1,1,1)}$

**Questions**:

How can I solve this exercise? Am I supposed to find a matrix?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have tried to combine everything in a matrix.

Comment: You have to write down each vector of the basis $\beta '$ as a linear combination of the vectors of the basis $\beta$.

Comment: @AlbertoAndrenucci Andrenucci I tried to do the following: $\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: However I got a matrix for each transformation, is this supposed to happen?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a first step:

Let $\beta = \{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ and $\beta' = \{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$.  We note that
$$
\operatorname{id}(v_1) = v_1 = \frac 23 w_1 + (-1)w_2 + \frac 13 w_3
$$
As such, we will find that
$$
\mathcal M^{\beta}_{\beta'}(\operatorname{id}) = \pmatrix{2/3 &?&?\\-1&?&?\\1/3&?&?}
$$

Comment: How did you come up with those values? I am not understanding it.

Comment: @PedroGomes you need to solve a system of equations in order to find those numbers. Equivalently, you can use the inverse of a certain matrix.